# BlazorInputFile - Synchronous reads are not supported

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to use SteveSanderson's BlazorInputFile  [package](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile) to upload files in a Blazor WASM app. (Server/Client setup). I installed the package according to the instructions on his [blog post.](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/)

My api takes in the file in a byte[] so I am converting the file from a Stream to byte[], and then posting to my API endpoint in the Server.

```
private async Task Upload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyTo(ms);
    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
    UploadFile file = new UploadFile
    {
        FileName = e.File.Name,
        FileContent = bytes,
        Size = e.File.Size,
        ContentType = e.File.ContentType
    };
        await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<UploadFile>("/api/uploadfile", file);
        await OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Unfortunately I keep getting an error/exception from BlazorInputFile which says "Synchronous reads are not supported".

I have tried to search the error and had various fixes (Browser adblocker could be blocking etc) but not of them has fixed the problem.

Comment: How to: ASP.NET Core Blazor file uploads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looks like the issue is you are using the synchronous version of Stream.CopyTo Method which is the reason you are getting the error message about synchronous reads not being supported.
I believe changing that line to:

```
await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
```

Will most likely solve your issue.

Comment: Wow that was so quick. I've been banging my head for a couple of hours trying to find the problem. Thankyou so much! (Answer works and my upload is now working perfectly)